# How to set User Interaction enabled in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `UITableview`(grouped). I have disabled the user interaction in xib. But, I want to enable the interaction for one cell. How can I enable this? I have used `[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:yes]` which is not working. `-tableView didselectrowindexpath` is not getting called. Can any one suggest me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Configure the cell

     if (indexPath.row == yourcell)
       cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Hope,this will help you

Comment: Ya its working fine..one more query..if i want set the selection (none/single selection / multiple selection) from code level how can I do?

Comment: [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

Comment: thats wt i want...thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

enable the user interaction in Xib. 
add

```
if(indexPath.row != YOUR ROW NO)
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

// To enable or disable user Interaction in particular Cell , you can try below code

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//i have used guard statment for creating object of class you can also use if you wish

```
    guard  let createCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Create") as? CreateProfileCell else {           
        return CreateProfileCell()
    }
```

//now You can enable or disable user interaction in cell you want as i did below

switch indexPath.row {

```
    case 0:

         createCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false . // false to disable interaction
    case 1:
   createCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // true to enable interaction

    case 2:

         createCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    default:

      print("try again")
    }
```

return createCell
}